# Existence of the optimal control in finite horizon MDP

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

For infinite horizon MDP with finite state and action space, there exists an optimal (stationary) policy. For finite horizon MDP with finite state and action space, does there exist an optimal policy? If so, are there any assumptions? Is the optimal policy non-stationary?

Comment: Does https://towardsdatascience.com/why-does-the-optimal-policy-exist-29f30fd51f8c answer (most of) your questions?

Comment: @jbowman Thanks for your reply but this one is for infinite time horizon MDP.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @jbowman for referring the book *Markov Decision Processes: Discrete Stochastic Dynamic Programming* by Martin L. Puterman. According to Chapter 4 of the book, when considering the class of history dependent stochastic policies with no extra assumptions on the the state and action space, the optimal policy needs not to exist (Chapter 4 Section 1.2 page 79). The author later proves in Proposition 4.4.3 that with finite state and action space, there exists an optimal Markovian deterministic policy.